# Active Directory whenChanged attribute

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to find out incremental changes with the novell c# ldap library and saw that active directory has an attribute "whenChanged" in each object which timestamps when the object has changed last. My issue is, that it doesn't seem to change when I delete a user from a group or a group from a organization.

Is there a way to see these changes(added user, deleted user, added group, deleted group) on group and OU basis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `whenChanged` attribute does change when any other attribute on the object changes. But it's important to note that:

1. If you remove a user from a group, it is the group that changes, not the user. So the user's `whenChanged` attribute will not be updated.
2. The `whenChanged` attribute is not replicated between domain controllers, so the value will not match between your domain controllers. Most of the time they will be pretty close, though.

For example, let's say you remove a user from a group. That means the `member` attribute of the group has changed and the `whenChanged` attribute is updated because of that. These updates happen on one domain controller. Because `member` is a replicated attribute, then the new `member` value is replicated to the domain controllers and the `whenChanged` attribute on those DCs is updated to *the time the replication occurred*, which will not match the `whenChanged` value on the DC where the change was actually made.

If you are not seeing the `whenChanged` attribute change on a group after modifying the membership, then it is possible you are getting the value from a different DC than the change was made on and you haven't waited long enough for replication to occur.